# How to run Ruby code from terminal?

Tags: ruby, console, terminal

I need to run a few lines of Ruby code from terminal, but I can't find the needed parameter for it.

Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a Ruby script in Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721369/how-to-execute-a-ruby-script-in-terminal)

Comment: You can use online IDE to run your code. That's possible write code or upload file.
https://repl.it/languages/ruby

Answer (score 205):

If Ruby is installed, then

```
ruby yourfile.rb
```

where `yourfile.rb` is the file containing the ruby code.

Or

```
irb
```

to start the interactive Ruby environment, where you can type lines of code and see the results immediately.

Comment: `irb` was the solution for me

Answer (score 62):

You can run ruby commands in one line with the `-e` flag:

```
ruby -e "puts 'hi'"
```

Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby) for more information.

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky You need to `require 'date'`.

So: `ruby -e "require 'date'; Date.new(2012,12,31).yday"`

Comment: You probably also want to print the result to stdout: `ruby -r date -e "puts Date.new(2012,12,31).yday"`

Comment: @JoshuaCheek +1 for mentioning the `-r` flag.