# How Do I Create a Ruby App that Can Run Without Calling "Ruby" in the Terminal?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I know that similar questions have been asked previously, but how do I go about building a Ruby file that can be run in the terminal without typing "ruby" before it?

The end goal here is to create a command line toolkit-type thing. Right now, in order to do what I want the user to be able to do, they must type

```
ruby Cherry init file_name
```

into the terminal.

What I would like, is the following:

```
Cherry init file_name
```

Is there anything I can add to the *ruby file itself* that allows it to be run with Ruby automatically, just by calling the name of the file? If not, how would I go about doing that? Any and all help is appreciated, as the other similar threads had no answers which I could understand.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721369/how-to-execute-a-ruby-script-in-terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your script has a correct shebang line, e.g. something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Also, make sure that the user trying to run the script has read and execute permissions for the script file.

That is all you need to do. Assuming you have a Ruby execution engine installed, and its executable is named `ruby` and it is in your `$PATH`, then you can execute your script file like any other executable.

Comment: "Execute permissions" can be set with `chmod +x script_name`.

Comment: Note that the current directory is generally *not* in `$PATH` (and shouldn't be). That means you need to put the script in a suitable binaries directory. `/usr/local/bin/` is good, or you can make your own personal binaries directory and add it to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Or run the script with `./scriptpath`. That still runs it without typing `ruby`